# Instance of Realm Object subclass is null when init

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm new to iOS development and swift, and I'm using Realm for my swift project.

First, I create a subclass of Realm Object:

```
enum EnumA: Int {
    case ValueA
    case ValueB
}

class ClassA: Object {

    var propA: EnumA = EnumA.ValueA
    var propB: Double = 0.0

}
```

Then I have another class:

```
class ClassB: Object {

    var id = 0
    var name: String = ""
    let aLotOfA = List<ClassA>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}
```

Then I create instance of ClassB somewhere:

```
class ClassC: NSObject {
    static let cManager = ClassC()

    func defaultB() -> ClassB {
        let instanceA = ClassA()
        let instanceB = ClassB()
        instanceB.name = "String"
        instanceB.aLotOfA.append(instanceA)
        return instanceB
    }
}
```

And I have this class:

```
class ClassD: Object {
    let aB: ClassB = ClassC.cManager.defaultB()
}
```

When I call `defaultB()`, the first line (`let instanceA = ClassA()`) makes instanceA null. I keep receiving message in the console like this:

```
"Object type '(null)' does not match RLMArray type 'ClassA'."
```

or

```
"The `ClassD.aB` property must be marked as being optional."
```

I don't know what's wrong here. Please someone help me, thanks very much.

And my environment:

Mac OS X 10.11.1 + Xcode 7.1

Realm is latest (Just downloaded from realm.io)

Base SDK: iOS 9.1

Deployment Target: iOS 9

Comment: According to Realm docs, try to replace your variables declarations:
`var variable`
with:
`dynamic var variable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [zuziaka](/users/4495682/zuziaka), you will need to declare all your persisted properties with `dynamic var`. This doesn't apply for `List` and `RealmOptional` properties.

Furthermore Realm doesn't support enums. You will need to declare your property `ClassA.propA` as `Int` and use the `rawValue` to initialize its default value:

```
class ClassA {
    var propA: Int = EnumA.ValueA.rawValue
    …
}
```

To-one relationships must be always marked as optional. That's here the case for the property `ClassD.aB`.